# deference between AsyncHBaseSink and HbaseSink

Tags: hbase, flume

in flume I read that there is two sinks for Hbase, so  what is the deference betwen them (AsyncHBaseSink and HbaseSink), and when to use each one ?

Answer (score 0):

Flume has two HBase Sinks, the HBaseSink(org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink) and AsyncHBaseSink(org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink). These two sinks will eventually converge to similar functionality, but currently each has some advantages over the other:

```
The AsyncHBaseSink currently gives better performance than the HBaseSink, primarily because it makes non-blocking calls to HBase.
The HBaseSink will soon support secure HBase clusters (FLUME-1626) and the new HBase IPC which was introduced in HBase 0.96.
```

In case of the HBaseSink, the serializer converts a Flume Event into one or more HBase Puts and/or Increments. The serializer must implement the HbaseEventSerializer. The serializer is instantiated when the sink is started by the Flume configuration framework. For each event processed by the sink, the sink calls the initialize method in the serializer. The serializer must “translate” the Flume Event into HBase puts and increments which should be returned by getActions and getIncrements methods.  These puts and increments are then sent over the wire to the HBase cluster. When the sink stops, this instance of the serializer is closed by the HBaseSink.

The AsyncHBaseSink’s serializer must implement AsyncHbaseEventSerializer.

In this case, the initialize method is called once by the sink, when it starts up. For every event, the sink calls the setEvent method and then calls the getActions and getIncrements methods - similar to the HBaseSink. When the sink is stopped, the serializer’s cleanUp method is called. Notice that the methods do not return the standard HBase Puts and Increments, but PutRequest and AtomicIncrementRequest from the asynchbase API. These are roughly equivalent to the HBase Puts and Increments respectively, with some differences.